# Pandas Series.str.replace () doesn't work in my case

Tags: python, pandas

`Series.str.replace()` doesn't work in csv file. I have column named `'property_location'` in the DataFrame. I want to replace value in the column:

```
loc_dict={
'Yeniyol':'Ismayilli',
}
df['property_location']=df['property_location'].replace(loc_dict)
```

When I check the column's string values, I notice that

`'Yeniyol'` hasn't been replaced and I don't receive any error messages:

```
df['property_location'].unique()

array(['Ağstafa', 'Yeniyol', 'Kürdǝmir'], dtype=object)
```

But when I copy paste from the output values it works, but when I type manually it doesnt, seems there is encoding issue. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: It will work, perhaps your actual code has some bug that your sample code does not show.

Comment: Maybe i should set some encoding attributes when reading csv (pd.read_csv) ?